# LLVM memory corruption

Tags: c++, llvm

I have some C++ memory corruption problems in an LLVM pass and I don't know how to solve them. Here is my piece of code :

in a large loop for each basic block I have :

```
std::vector<Value*> values(cnt);

// Value** values=new Value*[cnt];
// for(gy=0;gy<cnt;gy++){
//   values[gy] = new Value;
// }

if(is)
{
    LLVMContext& C = is->getContext();
    errs()<<"\ni: \n";


    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++){
        values[i]=ConstantInt::getSigned(Type::getInt64Ty(C),myArray[i]);
         errs()<<" "<<myArray[i];
     }

    //SmallVector<Value*>* bla = new SmallVector<Value*>(200);
      std::vector<Value*> bla(200);
      //SmallVector<Value*,200> bla;

       for(i=0;i<cnt;i++){
          bla.push_back(values[i]);
       }

       is->setMetadata("path",MDNode::get(C,bla));

       errs()<<"\nmodified instr  "<<*is<<"\n";

       if( (is->getMetadata("path")) ){ 
           for(i=0;i<cnt;i++){
             if(is->getMetadata("path")->getOperand(i)) {
                 errs()<<"\nget instr  "<<*(is->getMetadata("path")->getOperand(i))<<"\n";
              }
           }
        }

    bla.clear();

       //for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
         //delete values[i];

}
values.clear();
```

The error is:

```
opt: malloc.c:3790: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb)' failed.
```

with nothing printed from the loop (only when I get to the 7th basic block, that is similar to the others).

I also tried the alternatives that are commented `//` in the code. Maybe the stack memory becomes somehow corrupted, and I need to allocate the vectors/arrays on heap (i tried some variants)? I also tried to delete first the elements from vectors/arrays and then delete the pointer to the array/vector.
I have to mention that when the metadata that I have to add was not so big (only 18 operands instead of 72), it worked well.
Do you think maybe it is worth to use Valgrind? How it can help me?

Thank you for any suggestion !

...........

As an update, I receive a memory corruption error at some basic blocks. Here are the debug outputs:

1. opt - `opt: malloc.c:3801: _int_malloc: Assertion (unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb) failed.`
2. gdb -

   ```
   Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
   0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
   ```
3. valgrind - it executes all the code and at the problematic loop iteration I have :

   ==5134== Invalid write of size 4
   ==5134==    at 0x4039280: (anonymous namespace)::Hello::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) (in /home/alex/llvm/Release+Asserts/lib/Hello.so)
   ==5134==    by 0x8E33DE3: llvm::MPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) (in /home/alex/llvm/Release+Asserts/bin/opt)
   ==5134==    by 0x8E3726F: llvm::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) (in /home/alex/llvm/Release+Asserts/bin/opt)
   ==5134==    by 0x8E37385: llvm::PassManager::run(llvm::Module&) (in /home/alex/llvm/Release+Asserts/bin/opt)
   ==5134==    by 0x41AE4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
   ==5134==  Address 0x46cfa40 is 0 bytes after a block of size 200 alloc'd
   ==5134==    at 0x402C454: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
   ==5134==    by 0x4037AE0: (anonymous namespace)::Hello::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) (in /home/alex/llvm/Release+Asserts/lib/Hello.so)

and repeating.

```
==5230== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5230==     in use at exit: 95,110 bytes in 317 blocks
==5230==   total heap usage: 33,395 allocs, 33,078 frees, 4,484,753 bytes allocated
==5230==
==5230== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5230==    definitely lost: 7,732 bytes in 31 blocks
==5230==    indirectly lost: 85,864 bytes in 275 blocks
==5230==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5230==    still reachable: 1,514 bytes in 11 blocks
==5230==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5230== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==5230==
==5230== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5230== ERROR SUMMARY: 16432 errors from 15 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I assume the main problems are:
1. I don't allocate well memory for values. Or maybe I am allocating only for Value* pointers, not for the actual values. Maybe I don't free the mem.
2. I cannot use array instead of vector, since is->setMetadata("path",MDNode::get(C,values)); won't let me.

Do you think maybe it is worth to use Valgrind? How it can help me? I want only to attach some integers as metadata, one integer per operand.

Thank you for any suggestion !

Comment: Did you try running with a debug build of LLVM and see the stack trace for the assertion?

Comment: yes, it is a debug build (but i see no debug info). at what exactly should i look?

Comment: You can run `opt` in gdb and ask for a stack trace when the assertion is hit

Comment: ok, 1. gdb - Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted. 0xb7fd424 in_kernel_vsyscall ()  2. fully run, but where it stopped: "Invalid read of size 4 " at some addresses and by other addresses, Addresses 0x46cfa50 is 0 bytes after a block of size 200 alloc'd, LEAK SUMMARY: lost bytes